# How to change the form action based on controllers in layouts view cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in app/View/layouts/default.ctp. Here i specified a action for the form.But if we specified an action in the default that is available throughout the project.But my need is the form action should change based on the controller.

app/View/layouts/default.ctp

```
<form method="GET" action="projects">
  <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." 
      name="searchtext">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-
         search"></i></button>
     </span>
 </div>
</form>
```

In the above mentioned form action is projects.In home page it will be fine.But if the user is in different controller then action should be that controller.Is there is any way to change the form action depend on the controllers in layouts view?

Comment: You need to get controller name using `$this->param['controller']` and then assign to view. In view, set that in action.

Comment: Thanks for your help.The solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="GET" action=<?php echo $this->params['controller']; ?>>
  <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..." 
      name="searchtext">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-
         search"></i></button>
     </span>
 </div>
</form>
```